# GSM Calls with RILD in Android?

Tags: android, encryption, cryptography, gsm, ril

Is there way to initiate `GSM` call with Radio Interface Layer Daemon and it's `AT` Commands in Android? My real intention is encrypt voice data and send it from gsm network.

Can RILD is able to send encrypted voice data over GSM?

Comment: I don't know why guys voted to close this question, IMO it is clear

Comment: There are some similar questions like this one( about GSM voice Encyrption etc..) I read something on internet for RILD and I thought   must asked for it.

Comment: Looks similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363386/doing-advanced-stuff-with-at-commands-on-android which did not get an answer, but maybe the link could help you.

Comment: Have you found anything??

Comment: Nope,I've turn it to another way i used SIP && XMMP protocols for establish a secure connections for VoIP communications which had encryption.